# Commonly ommited from Arur Haman

Tags: tefilla, megillat-esther, nuschaot

Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 690:16 [says](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9008&st=&pgnum=607)

> One must say "Accursed is Haman, blessed is Mordechai, accursed is Zeresh, blessed is Esther, **accursed are all who hate HaShem, blessed are all who believe in HaShem**," and one must say "And also Charvonah should be remembered for good."

Other editions of the Shulchan Aruch have different versions of the bolded phrases. However, in many congregations, and in the ArtScroll siddurim, these words are completely omitted. Why?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9377&st=&pgnum=425

Comment: In the new print of Machzor Vitri Chelek 2:pg 359 has a lot of sources in the footnotes.

Comment: See also Tur 690:16 who brings Yerushalmi.

Comment: +1. The Aruch Hashulchan [is also bewildered by this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&st=&pgnum=465) (although he has the version:ארורים כל הרשעים ברוכים כל הצדיקים), which at least shows that Artscroll is merely following the practice of earlier siddurim.

Comment: It is in the artscroll hebrew,and other siddurim some in parentheses and some not,they use the girsa of Tosfos in Bavili megila 7b based off Yerushalmi,even though Yerushalmi is much shorter version

Comment: i am not really sure, my artscroll siddur has it

Comment: Which edition are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are, in fact, a wide variety of variant forms of this passage in *Shoshanas Yaakov* (which is itself something of [a synthesis of earlier sources](http://shesileizeisim.blogspot.com/2012/03/structure-of-shoshanas-yaakov.html)). The general assumption appears to be that this passage was modified, and even removed, due to "censorship" (which can mean actual censorship by non-Jewish authorities or self-censorship to avoid provoking the non-Jewish authorities). This censorship affected not only the text of the siddur but also the text of the basic sources, including the Tur, Shulchan Aruch, and even the Talmud Yerushalmi. (Thus we find variant texts in this regard in these works as well.) (See, in no particular order, the discussion [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46156&st=&pgnum=73&hilite=), [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14392&st=&pgnum=569&hilite=), [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&st=&pgnum=636&hilite=), [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13064&st=&pgnum=117&hilite=), and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24419&st=&pgnum=79&hilite=). And some relevant source material [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43543&st=&pgnum=136&hilite=).)

Given the difficulty in ascertaining the correct language, and the fact that there are concerns about some of these versions, it isn't surprising that some publishers continue to omit the passage.